# Assumptions about dwPageSize on different systems

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, winapi, virtual-memory

Can we make any assumptions about SYSTEM_INFO dwPageSize on different systems, when targeting the same architecture (ie. x86_64)?

I generate some custom native code, that is loaded alongside a C++-application via VirtualAlloc. This code has 3 different sections (code, cdata, dynamic static variables), that all need different protections (execute; read; read-write) via VirtualProtect, and thus need to be in different pages. Code references cdata and static variables via RIP-relative addressing.

I'm wondering if I can assume that, if say, when building on x64, dwPageSize is 4096, it will also have that same value on other x64-systems (or at least smaller, but never larger)? If so, I can just take the RIP-relative addresses as-is, because I can ensure that all data is placed at the same page-sized relative offsets. If the pages on the target-system could potentially be larger, I would need to fixup those offsets on loading the code.

Comment: Technically no, there's a distinction between small and large pages.  Best to focus on [reasonable choices](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210510-00/?p=105200).

Comment: RIP-relative addressing works on *virtual* addresses.  Page size or being in the same page doesn't matter, just that the data is within +-2GiB (in virtual address-space) of the code that's referencing it.  Probably good to do one big VirtualAlloc and then VirtualProtect some to be code (exec+read) and some to be "static" data (read+write) after JITing the code.  Are you just saying you want to make sure you put the data far enough away from the code that you can VirtualProtect the code without making the data read-only?  Or is there already some code+data with existing RIP-relative offsets?

Comment: @PeterCordes Well the problem is that, in order to make the data read-only, it needs to be at the next pages boundary. So if my code is < 4096 bytes in length, constant data is being placed at byte 4096, and that page (up to 8192) is being made read-only. RIP-relative addressing will then look at an offset into the page, for example RIP+4050. If for some reason on a machine dwPageSize then was 16kb, I could not place the constant data at offset 4096 and give that are read-only protection. I would need to place it at 16kb up, which would require fixup of RIP-offsets, would it not?

Comment: So you already have machine code with some existing offsets that assume data will be only about 4K away from the code?  IDK why this has to get loaded dynamically at all (vs. just linked into your executable's text and data/rdata sections), but maybe you have a choice of a bunch of different implementations and pick one of them to load or something.

Comment: Anyway, with a larger page size, say 16K, and an 8K binary blob with one 4K page each of code and data: you could load it at 12K into a 32K allocation, so the split between code and data is across a 16K page boundary.  Or if the data is just read-only constants, you could just have code+data in the same read+exec page.  (Assuming you don't have other code to put in the rest of the 16K page if you did split things; separate code vs. read-only data is mostly for iTLB vs. dTLB coverage, but you'd have 1 entry either way whether it's the same entry or not for L2TLB.)

Comment: Keeping constant data in non-executable pages is preferable for hardening against finding ROP and Spectre gadgets in the bytes of the data, but that's a pretty minor thing for something that's randomly placed relative to the main code every run.  So you might just let the second VirtualProtect fail (trying to remove exec permission) from the second 4K page, in the hypothetical situation where your program runs on a machine with larger pages.

Comment: @PeterCordes My use-case is a custom compiler for a scripting-language backend. The language has a high-level bytecode interface, and gets compiled to native machine code as an optimization. This code gets shipped alongside a (game) executable. So that code I'm talking about cannot be linked into an existing executable (I also don't want to deal with creating actual DLLs with PE or something).
I think the suggestion about letting VirtualProtect fail is a good one. I just need to make sure that in such a case, the exec-protection is not removed from the following code segment. Sounds doable.

Comment: I still don't get why you wouldn't compile to machine-code + data in a `.o` or `.obj` that could get linked normally, instead of this custom format that you have to write your own loader for, unless there's more going on that makes that not a good option for some reason. (Like that you'd have to generate relocation metadata in the .o) But ok, sure. And it's not a JIT so running on a new machine couldn't just re-compile from the bytecode.

Comment: Anyway, for testing you could try your code with your page-size constant set to 2048, half the actual size, and make sure it degrades gracefully / fails safe.  That might be safer and easier to get right than querying the page-size and allocating enough space for the code/data boundary to fall on a page boundary (assuming there are only two sections, code and rdata)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think the reasoning why I think it makes sense to not use an .obj, aside from me not wanting to deal with interfacing with an existing compiler, would be too much for the comment-section here. FWIW I used to compile the code on the hosts machine, like a JIT, but I always compiled all code at once, so I went with precompiled code to cut down on load-times. 
Your second suggestion is a good idea for testing, I'll definately do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page size is usually dictated by the processor architecture itself, although sometimes a processor architecture may support multiple page sizes. Nonetheless, Microsoft decided for one particular page size per architecture, so it is indeed safe to assume that the page size will be the same for a given architecture (and bitness of Windows) regardless of which machine the code is running on.

In all of the currently supported architectures the page size is 4KB, by the way. (Some discontinued architectures used 8KB.) See [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210510-00/?p=105200) for a full list.

Especially in regards to x86-64 you can be sure it won't change because the processor doesn't offer any other choice than 4KB (for small pages). Microsoft *may* theoretically change it in some architecture like ARM but that would be quite unexpected to me as it would cause a ton of compatibility issues with no discernible advantage.

Answer (score 2):

There's no forseeable way for x86-64 to have a different page-size in the future; that would require a different page-table format.  (Or for OSes to only support 2M largepages, but that's too large as a minimum size for most uses.)

Other ISAs do have a range of page-sizes to choose from but I agree with CherryDT's guess that it's unlikely Windows would change to a different page-size: you are far from the only person with a use-case where baking in a compile-time-constant page size would be convenient, so there's lots of software in the wild that would break.

---

Apparently your use-case is a custom binary format with machine-code + some read-only data.  That's convenient: read-only data still works perfectly fine if it's in a read+exec page instead of a purely read-only page, even if code also executes from that page.  If one page fits all of your code+data anyway (so you're not requiring 2 dTLB and/or 2 iTLB entries by mixing code+data when 1 each was possible with separation), the only downside is that you have some data in a page that didn't need to be executable.  This makes it a possible target for ROP and Spectre gadgets, which is usually not a big deal especially if it's at a random address every run.

So you have two good options for the unlikely hypothetical future case of running on a system with a larger page size:

- Arrange things so one of the `VirtualProtect` / `mprotect` system calls fails, leaving everything read+exec.  e.g. memory-map the whole file READ|EXEC, then attempt to VirtualProtect the last `n * 4K` to just READ.  It will fail if the offset relative to the start of the mapping wasn't a multiple of the page size.

  You can test this by building with `page_size = 2048` or `1024` to test what happens if the run-time page-size is 2x or 4x what you built for.  (With a mock-up binary blob I guess, not one that already has code and data separate by 4K).

  If you're not JITing new machine code or fixing up anything, it is best to just map the existing file so you have a file-backed mapping the OS can evict under memory pressure without paging out to the pagefile (like would happen with an anonymous allocation and then copying the file data into it.)
- Or, the other strategy: Allocate more than 1 page of the actual runtime page-size, and load your binary data such that the split between its code and data falls on the split between pages.  The first byte of the code won't be at the first byte of the allocation, so supporting that might require more tracking (two pointers instead of one), which is less desirable for something we expect never to happen anyway.

  For example, say 16K page size, and you're loading an 8K binary blob with 4K each of code and data: you could load it at 12K into a 32K allocation, so the split between code and data is across a 16K page boundary.  This works for read+write data, not just constants.

  Having a read+write+exec page is possible if the OS doesn't enforce W^X (write exclusive-or exec).  But on x86-64 hardware with self-modifying-code detection that nukes the pipeline if stores are too near code, you don't want read+write data in the same page as code.  (Big-cores like Skylake have 64-byte cache-line granularity for SMC detection, but low-power cores might be coarser.  Last I looked, Intel's optimization manual still recommended code and read+write data be in separate pages.)

  This split mapping scheme probably makes a file-backed mapping impossible, so that's another downside.  For Linux `mmap`, the file offset for the start of a mapping has to be a multiple of the page-size, so the mapping can share pages with the pagecache.  I assume Windows is the same.

---

> My use-case is a custom compiler for a scripting-language backend. The language has a high-level bytecode interface, and gets compiled to native machine code as an optimization. This code gets shipped alongside a (game) executable. So that code I'm talking about cannot be linked into an existing executable (I also don't want to deal with creating actual DLLs with PE or something). I think the suggestion about letting VirtualProtect fail is a good one. I just need to make sure that in such a case, the exec-protection is not removed from the following code segment. Sounds doable. –

I still don't get why you wouldn't compile to machine-code + data in a `.o` or `.obj` that could get linked normally, instead of this custom format that you have to write your own loader for.  Maybe there's more going on that makes that not a good option for some reason.  Like maybe you want to select the right binary optimized for the hardware.  Or maybe you just didn't want to deal with object file format handling to generate relocation metadata in the .o / .obj files that a linker fills in when linking them into the main executable binary.

But ok, sure. And it's not a JIT so running on a new machine couldn't just re-compile from the bytecode with data+code distance large enough to let them be in separate pages.

You *could* generate your binary blobs with 32K granularity or something for start-of-section, so larger page sizes won't be a problem.  But in a simple file format, that means padding.  After mapping the whole file, you could unmap the unused pages between code and data (which fails if the page-size is larger than you expect.)

Or to avoid padding in the file, start with a 64K mapping with read|exec to let the OS pick a free region with 64K of contiguous virtual address-space.  Then do the equivalent of `mmap(start+32K, ..., MAP_FIXED|MAP_PRIVATE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE)` to map the same part of the same file in the second region, so the distance between code and data in memory is always 32K larger than the distance between their file offsets.

This means the code bytes are there in the data page but you don't use them, and the data bytes are there in the code page but you don't use them.  Mapping the same page of file data twice is something Linux executables used to do, before `ld` started padding sections to keep bytes out of executable pages if they didn't need to be there.

On systems with 4K pages like we expect, all the code can be unmapped from the data mapping and vice versa.  Unless the code+data total is under 4K, then you have two mappings of the same page.

Comment: Some of the factors for not using obj-files:
- Not wanting to deal with obj file format, as you assessed
- Little point in going for a full binary executable format, as externally most functions are called via reflection/script-bindings
- No specific executable is even generated for the packaged application (just a generic exe+dlls), so linking this way would mean I'd have to set that up first.
- Certain properties that make me unsure if obj would even work (64-bit addresses of dynamic objects are placed in the code directly; etc...)

Comment: Maybe all of this would work with obj-files being linked in some sort of specific executable. But it doesn't seem naturally the right solution for my workflow (where script-data is embedded in the games/applications data-format, which used to be bytecode and is now native code).

Comment: @Juliean: The easy way around that particular point is to compile to assembly language, with `section .data` and `section .text` directives, and let it generate object files.  This is one major reason that many compilers compile to asm instead of directly to machine code.  (e.g. GCC and many less-popular compilers with less development time sunk into them than clang/LLVM or MSVC).  Then you have a build dependency on an assembler like NASM or GNU Binutils, though.

Comment: @Juliean: Object files can be linked into DLLs, same way a DLL is built from multiple compiler-generated `.obj` files.  Anyway, you have a working system now, and memory-mapping some simple code + read-only-data files is totally fine, especially if you wanted to indirect through a pointer for calls into them anyway, like rolling your own `dlopen`.  (If you did link the hypothetical `.obj` files directly into your DLL, you could have declared prototypes for their functions and directly called them from other functions in the DLL, with the compiler using `call rel32` instructions.)

Comment: Yes, as you said, things are working that way now; and I wouldn't want to introduce many dependencies or complicate the process too much further. I do appreciate the input though. I think the point for calling my functions from inside the same DLL isn't really useful for that specific scenario. As I mentioned, all those functions are mainly called via some reflection interface. While I can get a function-pointer to call, after compiling to native code, each piece of code that would use such a function-pointer could potentially use any, and not one specific that can be specified via linking.

Comment: To make it more clear, here is a short pastebin to show how such a method is called: https://pastebin.com/35XEKFpu
m_method is a wrapper around calling from eigther bytecode or native code, and CompositeEventBinding can be instantiated many times with different "methods". Does that clarify how calling functions directly from DLL would not work in my case; or am I missing what you actually meant?

Comment: @Juliean: Ok, so there's already some indirection baked in to how you call anyway so pointers into a memory-mapped region couldn't go away and turn into direct calls anyway.  So the only advantage of having the code in the `.text` section of your DLL would be iTLB locality and disk-cache effects.  (And no separate file, and no custom loader to maintain, but instead a table of function addresses to maintain I guess.)

Comment: Precisely. All methods from within the generated code already call themselves using rel-offsets, and the application only calls entry-points via indirection. I'll note down those advantages you mention, to consider in the future.